# How do I create a new model object that references two other objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table `reviews`. Both `users` and `movies` have many reviews. A review is a tuple `(id, movie_id, user_id, rating, comment)` that references both a `movie` and `user`. If on the `movie` show page I add a button "Post review", that links to `new_review_path`, how would I forcefully access and set the `user_id` and `movie_id` references from inside of the `reviews_controller`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming one `Review` object belongs to both `User` and `Movie` at a time, for that case you can use nested routing to get `movie_id` in the URL

```
resources :movies do
  resources :reviews
end
```

And then inside review controller, you can fetch `Movie` object by,

```
movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
```

And I am assuming `User` object is the `current_user`, if that's the case you can do something like

```
Review.new(movie_id: movie.id, user_id: current_user.id)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thank you! Also, how would I pass my `rating` and `comment` into the `Review.new` call along with the IDs? I have access to `review_params`, could I access it from there?

Comment: You can create a form to pass those values to the action, if you have a doubt you can add a separate question for that.

Answer (score 0):

If `user` and `movies` both have `reviews` then you can use `polymorphic associations` for more details please review [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association) OR [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)